# With the help of a ruler and compass, construct a parallelogram DEFH where DE=4.5 cm, DF=3.5 cm

Tags: geometry

(continued) and the length of the perpendicular from D to EF is 2.5 cm

my work - https://vgy.me/WNP7rq.jpg

How do I construct the perpendicular from D to EF without knowing what the base for that perpendicular(DG) is?

Comment: You don't have to.  Just construct a 2.5 cm perpendicular for DE *anywhere*.  Then construct a line parallel but 25 cm away from DE.  Whereveer that line intersects your arc will be F.

Comment: Do not vandalize your own post by trying to render it meaningless.  You've received an answer.  It is rude to destroy the comprehensibility of a question after having received an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: There is a contradiction. $DFE$ is a right triangle, right angle is at $F$. Tangent line is $FE$. Length of $DF$ cannot be both normal length 2.5 cm as well as 4.5 cm at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't construct the one precise perpendicular from D that goes through F.  You can construct a *different* perpendicular that goes through a *different* point instead.

Construct a perpendicular from DE *anwhere*.  Tick of a point that is 2.5cm away from DE.  Call that point BANANNANANNAFOFANNA.  Construct a line through BANANNANANNAFOFANNA that is parallel to DE.

*NOW* find point F that the is on the line that is parallel to DE that contains BANANNANANNAFOFANNA so that DF = 3.5 cm.

Now erase BANANNANANNAFOFANNA and let's pretend BANANNANANNAFOFANNA never existed.

[image]